# How to make make a texture scale absolute

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes, vector-mapping

I'm trying to make a shader that has a texture that follows its surface (generated mapping/ object mapping) as well as having said texture stay the exact same scale regardless of distance and without doing it by hand.

Here is a visual of what I mean using two cubes that are 14 meters apart in the scene with a checker texture on them:

This is what I've got through mapping the texture using "generated" coordinates
[image]

This is what I'm looking for but without having to manually rescale the textures to make them match like I have done here.
[image]

I tried using all sorts of different combinations with the vector transform node, geometry, texture coordinate node, vector math node, but my lack of knowledge in this specific domain means I'm just trying stuff out and hoping for the best.

Anybody knows how to achieve this effect?

Comment: I think @Robin Betts has an answer about this

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great to hear!  This question will probably get closed as a duplicate by community votes.  There's no mark against your account, it just means that your question will remain here for search purposes, but no answers can be posted here.  Instead, the answer that helped you is linked on the right.  Feel free to ask more questions or provide answers, we're glad to have you.